# String replacement not working in powershell script at runtime

Tags: powershell

I have powershell file in which i have line of variable decalration as below

```
[string] $global:myExePath = "\\myshare\code\scripts";
```

I want to replace `\\myshare\code\scripts` with `\\mynewshare\code1\psscript` at runtime by executing a powershell script.

I am using 
 `Get-Content $originalfile | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "\\myshare\code\scripts", $mynewcodelocation.FullName } | Set-Content ($originalfile)`

If am execuing 
 `{ $_ -replace "scripts", $mynewcodelocation.FullName }` it is working fine, but it is not working for `{ $_ -replace "\\myshare\code\scripts", $mynewcodelocation.FullName }`

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'\' is a special regex character used to escape other special character.You need to double each back slash to match one back slash.

```
-replace "\\\\myshare\\code\\scripts",$mynewcodelocation.FullName
```

When you don't know the content of a string you can use the escape method to escape a string for you:

```
$unc = [regex]::escape("\\myshare\code\scripts")
$unc
\\\\myshare\\code\\scripts

-replace $unc,$mynewcodelocation.FullName
```